# How do i copy a specific word/number from a TXT file using Batch?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, text-editor

I need to search for a specific nubmer that comes after a string in a text file.
For example I have this data:

```
yyy = 80rr, xxx = 136rr, zzz = 95rr
```

and i want to copy the numbers that between `yyy` and `rr`, `xxx` and `rr`, `zzz` `rr`.

Then I want to echo these numbers. Is it possible?

Comment: Is your example a complete line, or may there be other text in this line? if yes, before and/or after?

Comment: yyyyyyy = 80rr, xxxxxxx = 136rr, zzzzzzz = 95rr
this is how it looks in the text file (with 4 spaces at the begining)

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "tokens=3,7delims=r " %%a IN (q28193214.txt) DO (ECHO "%%a" and "%%b")

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q28193214.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Answer (score 0):

What is your batch environmen? In an unix shell with awk this can be done easily:

```
echo "yyy = 80rr, xxx = 136rr, zzz = 95rr" | 
   awk '{ match($0, /yyy = ([0-9]*)rr, xxx = ([0-9]*)rr, zzz = ([0-9]*)rr/, a); print a[1] " " a[2] " " a[3]; }'
```

Comment: I have a text file named test with this data

    yyy = 80rr, xxx = 136rr, zzz = 95rr    
and i want to use these numbers in another batch file

Comment: use them as veriables

Comment: Okay, looking at the other answers, you probably have an windows environment.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

for /F "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do set "line=%%a"
set /A "%line:r=%"

echo yyyyyyy = %yyyyyyy%
echo xxxxxxx = %xxxxxxx%
echo zzzzzzz = %zzzzzzz%
```

For example:

```
C:\> type input.txt
    yyyyyyy = 80rr, xxxxxxx = 136rr, zzzzzzz = 95rr

C:\> test.bat
yyyyyyy = 80
xxxxxxx = 136
zzzzzzz = 95
```